# I want to have a source of the latest kernel to download it on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: kernel, synaptic, source

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , and I want to download the latest Linux Headers from Synaptic .. but I NEED a source ..

Comment: if you want the source then try to download it from terminal through `apt-get source` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the source code via `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install linux-source
```

After the command has finished, your linux kernel source code in the directory `/usr/src/`.

Alternatively you can download the sources from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/).

Comment: How do I use the source code in the directory .. I'm a beginner ..

Comment: I guess I should learn how to use those packages

Comment: That's a bigger thing, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile